# Squid silently fails when using https

Tags: https, squid

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

After installing squid3 (3.3.8-1ubuntu6.8), Squid starts successfully.

```
$ sudo service squid3 stop
$ sudo squid3 -N
...
```

I then replaced `http_port 3128` with `https_port 3128` and squid fails with no error messages.

```
$ sudo squid3 -N
$ echo $?
1
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a bit more than changing http to https. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you will need to setup Squid to act as reverse proxy (e.g. if you need SSL termination) or transparent proxy. I assume what you want is transparent proxy - Here is a great guide how to set up this https://www.tectut.com/2015/08/configure-squid-as-http-and-https-transparent-proxy/ . In terms of errors - squid keeps its logs in cache.log (the default location should be /usr/local/squid/var/logs but this could be something else depending on how you installed squid - I would recommend building from source). You can also add in your squid.conf file the following line `debug_options ALL,1` this should make squid output the debug logs in cache.log.